# Distortion of the Earth's magnetic field due to solar winds?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solar-system, geomagnetism, solar-wind

[image: Solar winds changing the shape of earth's magnetosphere]

Why and how do the solar winds distort the Earth's Magnetosphere to form a drop like shape facing away from the Sun?

Comment: Related question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410406/59023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plasma consists of ionized, and so charged, particles.So when you get the particles hitting the magnetic field they get pushed off the path they would have followed.

Then you get Lenz's law.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law

So when the magnetic field pushes the charges out, the induced field tries to cancel out the magnetic field. That squashes the field on the sun-side. Behind the Earth the field is trying to pull the particles in again. That induces a corresponding field in the other direction, which stretches out the Earth's field.